# DataFrame.groupby(TimeGrouper="d"): Invalid length for values or for binner

Tags: python, exception, pandas

I am trying to build groups of my data using the groupby function of pandas over a DataFrame with a DateTimeIndex. Using pd.TimeGrouper, I want to group by day.

When I define this DataFrame, the below operation `n.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("d"))` does not work.

```
n = pd.DataFrame(
    {"value": [5462,5462,3185]},
    index=[pd.to_datetime("2013-10-13 19:03:54"),
           pd.to_datetime("2013-10-12 19:03:54"),
           pd.to_datetime("2013-10-11 13:19:23")])
```

Error:

```
n.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("d"))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-120eaa65b064> in <module>()
----> 1 n.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("d"))

\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
    184         return groupby(self, by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
    185                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys,
--> 186                        squeeze=squeeze)
    187 
    188     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, normalize=False):

\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in groupby(obj, by, **kwds)
    531         raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))
    532 
--> 533     return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
    534 
    535 

\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
    195         if grouper is None:
    196             grouper, exclusions = _get_grouper(obj, keys, axis=axis,
--> 197                                                level=level, sort=sort)
    198 
    199         self.grouper = grouper

\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort)
   1268 
   1269     if isinstance(key, CustomGrouper):
-> 1270         gpr = key.get_grouper(obj)
   1271         return gpr, []
   1272     elif isinstance(key, Grouper):

\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.pyc in get_grouper(self, obj)
    106     def get_grouper(self, obj):
    107         # Only return grouper
--> 108         return self._get_time_grouper(obj)[1]
    109 
    110     def _get_time_grouper(self, obj):

\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.pyc in _get_time_grouper(self, obj)
    112 
    113         if self.kind is None or self.kind == 'timestamp':
--> 114             binner, bins, binlabels = self._get_time_bins(axis)
    115         else:
    116             binner, bins, binlabels = self._get_time_period_bins(axis)

\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.pyc in _get_time_bins(self, axis)
    146 
    147         # general version, knowing nothing about relative frequencies
--> 148         bins = lib.generate_bins_dt64(ax_values, bin_edges, self.closed)
    149 
    150         if self.closed == 'right':

\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.generate_bins_dt64 (pandas\lib.c:16139)()

ValueError: Invalid length for values or for binner
```

Surprisingly, when I define the DataFrame like below, it works just fine. Notice that I changed the last day to be 2013-10-12 instead of 2013-10-11.

```
n = pd.DataFrame(
    {"value": [5462,5462,3185]},
    index=[pd.to_datetime("2013-10-13 19:03:54"),
           pd.to_datetime("2013-10-13 19:03:54"),
           pd.to_datetime("2013-10-12 13:19:23")])
```

In this case I get a correct group object:

```
n.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("d"))
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000A3D84E0>
```

I already looked up some of the core functions of pandas in the source code, but I am not sure whether this is a bug or whether I just do not know how to use the function properly.

Notice also that aggregating on month works just fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: looks like a bug, have to look closer a bit later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, because the index is not ordered monotonically, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4161). but no reason to use `TimeGrouper`, this is somewhat internal ATM, use `resample`.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
                     value
2013-10-13 19:03:54   5462
2013-10-12 19:03:54   5462
2013-10-11 13:19:23   3185

In [4]: df.resample('d')
Out[4]: 
            value
2013-10-11   3185
2013-10-12   5462
2013-10-13   5462
```

Comment: +1 I thought about something like n.groupby(lambda x: x.day), but this one is better

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for your reply and this is a great idea, but it somehow does not really solve the complete problem. The standard grouping method of "resample" is "how='mean'". Is it defined anywhere how I can change that to something more useful? I have to apply a custom function. The point is that I also have multiple entries per day and your resample-solution is only correct with the "mean" method when there is only one entry per day.

Comment: you can pass a custom how if you would like, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling)

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! Although I already tried to use .resample() with a custom function, your link showed me what parameters are expected. This is the crucial aspect: "The how parameter can be a function name or numpy array function that takes an array and produces aggregated values [...]". Have a great day!